# AGAL Flickering and Sampling Artefacts

Tags: stage3d, agal

I've been creating cellular automata using AGAL and having some issues. My code basically does the following:

- Kicks off with a bitmap used to create a texture.
- Invokes setTextureAt() to pass the texture to context3D
- Applies that texture to a simple plane
- Does some cellular automata magic
- Renders to back buffer
- Also renders back to the same texture
- Repeats

I sample neighbouring pixels by adding the 1 / (width or height). I thought that mpimapping might help - but I can't see a way to mipmap generated textures.

You can see [the application here](http://www.flexmonkey.co.uk/willamowsky-rossler-bin-release/WillamowskyRosslerAgalDemo.html) and the [source code is here](http://www.flexmonkey.co.uk/willamowsky-rossler-bin-release/srcview/index.html). The AGAL code lives in *classes.WillamowskyRosslerRenderer*

The code works, but I get these odd artefacts when I zoom in:

[image]

Many thanks in advance,

simon

**Update!** *I've been playing around and the artefacts and flickering have both vanished by:*

- *Setting the texture size to 2048 * 2048*
- *configureBackBuffer(1024,1024,16)*

*It's a workaround rather than a fix, so I'm still investigating*

Answer (score 0):

Yay! Fixed with mipmapping. I didn't realise that render to texture automatically creates mip maps so I can use proper filtering in the 'tex' calls.

Also, in this project, the back buffer needs to be the same aspect ratio as the texture

I blogged about it here: http://flexmonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/stage3d-joys-of-mipmapping.html